# Python permission error creating socket in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, socketcan

I am using [socketCAN](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/interfaces/socketcan.html) to interface to a CAN bus in Ubuntu 16.04. The interface works fine on my machine.  However, when I kick off our CI, it executes on a remote agent (also Ubuntu 16.04) and I am receiving a permission error when the socket is creation is attempted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from    tests_smoke             import SmokeTests
  File ".../tests_smoke.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tests.validate_can                 import ValidateCAN
  File ".../tests/validate_can.py", line 16, in <module>
    bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='can0', bitrate=250000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/can/interface.py", line 128, in __new__
    return cls(channel, *args, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/can/interfaces/socketcan/socketcan.py", line 459, in __init__
    self.socket = create_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/can/interfaces/socketcan/socketcan.py", line 330, in create_socket
    sock = socket.socket(PF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 134, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Being a novice in both Linux and Python, I'm not positive how to address this.  I read in a few places that this may be a file creation permission issue which is inherited from the calling process so I have placed a "os.umask(0)" at the beginning of the script and that had no impact.

I've also read that it may be necessary to run the script as root.  This seems quite risky.

What is the best way to fix this?